# external side effect in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, side-effects

Look at this code:

```
#include <framework_i_hate.h>
int main() {
  XFile file("./my_file.xxxx", "create");
  XObject object("my_object");
  // modify the object
  object.Write();
}
```

Try to guess where `object` will be saved... yes, you guessed it. I think this is too magic, I'd  like to write something like `object.Save(file)`, but it's not necessary. Obviously there is global variable inside `framework_i_hate.h` that it is modified during the `file` constructor. What do you think about this side effect inside constructor?

How can this behavior be hidden?

A bonus to who guess the framework.

Comment: @aaa: I think the best way to answer the question would be to do so, yes.

Comment: Should I tag this `[root-framework]`? In the end this is still too much of a rant and not really useful.

Answer (score 3):

Very muddled hard to understand post and the question in the end is very rhetorical.
Global variables are evil, what else to add?

Answer (score 2):

What can be said about this that isn't already obvious enough: It's a fairly nasty side effect, because:

- the resulting behaviour is unexpected and not predictable at all, unless you know that framework well.
- global program state usually isn't a good idea in object-oriented programming. (In fact, global state is probably never a good idea, so best avoid it if you can.)
- it's fairly likely that this framework isn't thread-safe, either. (Think about what happens when two concurrent threads both create an `XFile` object each, and one of these threads then writes an `XObject`... where will it end up being saved?)

While this thread is tagged C++ and not about .NET, I have seen this "anti-pattern" before in a less severe and much more sane form, namely with DB transaction scopes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to see the relationship between XFile and XObject be explicit, I agree that this "magic" is too well hidden. I also question why the object is given a name, unless there are other parts of the API where the name is significant.

Global variables are despised for many reasons, this is just one example.